# Fetching a file from a server with an iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios

How does one download or fetch a file using iOS?

I want to fetch a plist file from a server and open it within the app.

Does there need to be a php web client on the server or how would this be done, keeping security in mind to?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *address = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourwebsite.com/file.plist"];
NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:address];
```

Comment: What if there is no website, but just a server sitting on an ip address? Can the data not be downloaded in NSData and converted to a plist? Or how can I get it to a plist with key value pairs?

Answer (score 0):

with this You can fetch file content in a string.

```
NSURL *address = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourwebsite.com/file.plist"];
    NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:address encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

after fetching you can display this content in UITextView.

```
[youtextview setText:fileString];
```